# Backwards compatibility built on Xcode 9 to run on iPad version iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, entity

I have an issue my original application that was built on iOS version 9.0, my new release is built using Xcode 9.2 i set deployment target to 9.0.to be backward compatible to older iPads.. App crashes on trying to save to core data ' **Does not recognize Entity for name '** The Entity name is in my Core Data Stack , so I am not sure what is going on. Any guidance or ideas ?

Regards
JZ

Answer (score 0):

Hey JZ I know you asked this months ago - but see the answer to this question here: [Xcode: iOS backward and forward compatibility for Deployment Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615828/xcode-ios-backward-and-forward-compatibility-for-deployment-target).

Apparently, you have to target the minimum OS you wish to support, as compatibility only runs *forward* for iOS development.